# Setting fixed height for all cells at once in iText 2.0.7

Tags: itext

Is there anyway where we can set the height of each cell to a particular height? I created multiple cells using `PdfPCell`,the height is common to all the cells so I wanted to set the height of each cell at once to shorten my code, currently I am doing it using the `PdfPCell`'s `setFixedHeight` method.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the [default PdfPCell](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#getDefaultCell%28%29) and set its fixed height. All the cells of the `PdfPTable` will have the same height afterwards. This will have to be repeated for each table though.

Comment: It is not working for me,I am doing it in below way 

 float[] columnWidths = {1f, 1f, 1f,1f,1.5f,1.5f}; 
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6); 
table.setWidthPercentage(100); 
table.setWidths(columnWidths); table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(60f); 

 please let me know if I am missing something,I am using Itext for the first time

Comment: If you are using iText for the first time, what do you use such an old version? iText 2.0.7 is almost 5 years old, current version is 5.2.1